# why my wordpress post, created programmatically, not opening detail page & redirecting to index instead

Tags: posts

I created a post programmatically using python:

```
sql = "insert into `wp_18_posts` " \
          "(`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, " \
          "`post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`," \
          "`to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`," \
          "`guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`, `django_id`)" \
          " values " \
          "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

the post is showing up in database and also in index page, but once I click on that post, it is redirecting me back to index again. So detail page is not opening.

I am setting `post_status` to 'publish'.

I also set the taxonomy in mysql manually. but no success.

appreciate any hint..

Comment: Not sure about the sql, but you should check out WordPress rest api, and use it to insert the post. It has the added benefit of giving you proper response if the post was successfully inserted, along with the ID of the post. WordPress generates the ID of the post so probably that's what's messing with your inserted post.

Comment: Another possible cause for this can be your template. It might be redirecting post pages to index.